# Is there a situation in delphi where a GOTO is the only solution?

Tags: delphi, goto

The `goto` statement is taboo at my work.
So the following question is born...

Is there a situation possible where a `goto` is the only valid solution?

Comment: In nearly 20 years of Delphi and probably a few million lines I have never used a goto statement...

Comment: In Delphi-XE4 there are 14 `goto` statements under the source directory.

Comment: @LURD They mostly look justified apart from the two in MXDSSQRY

Comment: Isn't `try .. except` a goto ?  What about `Exit` and `Break`. Aren't they `gotos` too ? (`exit, break` and `abort` are abhorred in some companies I have worked for)

Comment: @Hugh What about if, or switch?

Comment: A nice article on this subject: [Goto Delphi: How I (Almost) Ended Up Using Goto in Delphi code](http://delphi.about.com/od/standards/a/goto_in_delphi.htm)

Comment: I've seen 'goto' used in language interpreters (eg Lisp interpreters written in Pascal). Even Wirth used a 'goto' in his PL/O program.

Comment: My old professor said that you could use any feature you like, but for "frowned upon" features you had to imagine having to write a A4 page essay to justify each use. If the essay wasn't worth the trouble, you don't need the construct. I think that is still a better system than ill informed blanket taboos. It forces people to think.

Comment: @No'amNewman: Wirth doing things a certain way isn't necessarily meaningful; languages have changed considerably in the last three or four decades, and what was accepted then is not always the case today.

Comment: Avoiding Goto, Avoiding Exit, and Avoiding Switch all lead to their own Pathological Forms of stupidity.   What I love is how the opponents of Goto, Exit, and Switches, create equally unreadable code without using any of them.

Comment: So are we making a case against ANY flow control statements here?  I think not.  Personally, I have never used a `goto`, `exit` I dont like much, and `break` I avoid.  It all depends on context though. One of these statements half way down a 2000 line procedure is atrocious, but mainly because of the 2000 line procedure.

Comment: can we talk about `with` now ? ;P

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Originally GOTO was added to Pascal for error handling, including inter procedural forms that Borland(/Embarcadero) never implemented (example: GOTOing from a inner procedure to the parent), just like Borland never implemented other inner function functionality like passing inner functions to procedure-typed parameters.(*)

In that way GOTO can be considered the precursor to exceptions.

There still some practical uses: The last time I checked, jumping out of a nested IF statement with goto was still faster in Delphi then letting the code exit from a nested if naturally.
Optimizations like these are sometimes used in e.g. compression code, and other complex tree processing code with deeply nested loops or conditional statements.

Such routines often still use goto for errorhandling, because it is faster. (exceptions are not only slow, but their border conditions inhibit some optimizations).

One could see this as part of the plain Pascal level of Object Pascal, just like C++ still allows plain C nearly completely.

(of course, since the optimized compression code in Delphi is only delivered in .o form, it is hard to find examples in the Delphi codebase. The JPEG code has some, but that is a C translation)

(*) Original pascal, and IIRC even Turbo Pascal doesn't allow prematurely exiting a procedure with EXIT. Same for CONTINUE and BREAK.

Comment: TP7 Had CONTINUE,BREAK and EXIT. The first two were introduced in TP7, while exit was before.

Answer (score 6):

> Is there a situation possible where a `GOTO` is the only valid solution?

I suppose it depends on what you mean by valid. I suppose you are asking if there exists a program that can only be written with the use of the `goto` statement. In which case the answer is that there is no such program. Delphi is Turing complete with or without the `goto` statement.

However, if we are prepared to widen the discussion to include other languages, there are situations where `goto` is a good solution, even the best solution. The scenario that most commonly comes to mind is implementing tidy-up and error handling in languages without structured exception handling. If you peruse the Linux source code you will find that `goto` is widely used. I expect that the same is true of the Windows source code.

Answer (score 3):

Goto is very old. It predates sub-routines like functions and procedures! It is also very dangerous and can make your code less readable (to others, or to yourself a few months later).

In theory it's not possible to have a situation where goto is required. I won't repeat the theory about Turing tape machines here, but using selection and iteration, you can re-order the code so in all possible input values the same output comes about.

In practice though, it's sometimes 'handy' and 'better readable' to 'jump away' from the flow of code in certain conditions, and that's where Exceptions come in. `raise` breaks away from the current execution, and *jump* to the closest `finally` or `except` section. This is safer because they work cascaded, and provide a better way to handle the context in case of one of these border conditions. (And there's also `break`and `abort` and `exit`)

Comment: Yeah, but the real stinger was the `ALTER` statement in COBOL, which could dynamically alter (indeed) the targets of a `GOTO` statement. So you couldn't even believe what your `GOTO` statement said ...

Comment: @marjan Sadly missing from COBOL is the COMEFROM statement.

Comment: Not in Pascal. It was added to Pascal specifically for error handling,

Comment: @DavidHeffernan: If I read it correctly you can never trust the flow you are reading without checking for `COME FROM` statements with the line number you are on? Triple Yikes!

Answer (score 3):

Something like 15 years ago I used the goto statement in Delphi to convert [one of Bob Jenkins's hash functions](http://burtleburtle.net/bob/hash/evahash.html) from C to Pascal. The C function has a switch() statement without breaks after each case, and you can't do that with Pascal's case statement. So I converted it into a bunch of Pascal labels and gotos. I guess you would still have to do it the same way with the newest Delphi versions.
Edit: I guess using gotos would still be a reasonable way to do this. Gets the job done, easy to understand, limited to a short block of code, not dangerous.

Comment: A C-style switch statement with 'break-less' cases, can be converted to a series of if statements, with `x and not(y)` for the cases without break, and will probably even compile to roughly the same assembler code.

Comment: The goto hack was at least very straight-forward to create at the time. For something a bit more complex, try converting J.R. Ullmann's graph isomorphism algorithm into readable non-spaghetti code. http://www.engr.uconn.edu/~vkk06001/GraphIsomorphism/Papers/Ullman_Algorithm.pdf

Comment: You would not **have** to do it that way.

Answer (score 3):

`GOTO` is never necessary. Any computable algorithm can be expressed with assignment and the combination of `IF`...`THEN`, `BEGIN`...`END`, and your choice of `WHILE`...`DO`...`END` or `REPEAT`...`UNTIL`. You don't even need subroutines. :)

This is known as the structured program theorem.

For a proof, see the 1966 paper, [Flow Diagrams, Turing Machines and Languages with Only Two Formation Rules (PDF)](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.119.9119&rep=rep1&type=pdf) by Corrado Böhm and Giuseppe Jacopini.